# An invertible matrix is a multiple of a matrix in $SL_n(\mathbb R)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups

I read that
For $n$ odd we have that $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is the internal direct product of $SL_n(\mathbb R)$ and the subgroup $SM_n(\mathbb R)$ of scalar matrices (a matrix in $SM_n(\mathbb R)$ is of the form $\lambda I_n$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R^*$).

So  $$GL_n(\mathbb R)=SL_n(\mathbb R)\times SM_n(\mathbb R)$$
and this would imply that any invertible matrix $M$ is the unique product of a matrix $A\in SL_n(\mathbb R)$ and a matrix $B\in SM_n(\mathbb R)$. So $M=A\lambda I_n$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R^*$ which means that 
$M=\lambda A$ so an invertible matrix has to be a multiple of a matrix in $SL_n(\mathbb R)$, this conclusion does not seem correct to me but I don't see where is the mistake I made in this reasoning.. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Santiago Actually what you need is $\sqrt[n]{\det M}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\det(M)=\lambda\neq 0$. Then $\lambda^{-1/n}M$ has determinant $1$, hence is in $SL_n(R)$, if the $n$-th root of $\lambda$ is real. This is only the case for $n$ odd.